# Not able to call multiple functions from one function in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, function, plpgsql, psql

Here are my two functions,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.insert_stagging()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
      BEGIN
         INSERT into stagging(data)
         select data from mytable where data not like 'table%';
      END;
  $function$;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clear_mytable2() 
    RETURNS TABLE(data1 text) as
$BODY$   
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY (select data from mytable2);
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Not able to call above two functions from another function,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test()
  returns void as
$func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT insert_stagging()';
    EXECUTE 'SELECT clear_mytable2()';
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

With the above code, I am only able to get the execution result of 1st function written inside the BEGIN clause, if I change the sequence of the **'SELECT insert_stagging()';** with **'SELECT clear_mytable2()';** then I'll only get the execution result from clear_mytable2() function.

How to execute both the function calls within 1 PostgreSQL function?

Answer (score 1):

When the function returns table, then returns result just to caller function. When the caller function ignores this result, then result is thrown.

If you want to call `void` function, then you should to use `PERFORM`. Using `EXECUTE` in this context is bad idea. This is designed to work with dynamic SQL. If you want to call table function, you have to use `RETURN QUERY` again:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_test()
  RETURNS TABLE(data1 text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
    PERFORM insert_stagging();
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM clear_mytable2();
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM func_test();
```